# Cannot get SSL working with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, https

Ok, so I'm trying to configure my server to accept SSL connections and I cannot get it working. I'm aware there are a lot of similar questions on the site, but each one I have come across so far doesn't seem to help.

I'll post as much information as possible and hopefully you'll be able to help.

My apache version is: 2.2.14 (running on Ubuntu). The information below seems to show that SSL is configured and running fine, but when I try to access https://website.com the request times out.

I got an SSL certificate through GoDaddy, and followed the process to generate the .crt file.

I have the following files:

```
/home/ubuntu/ssl/website.com.crt
/home/ubuntu/ssl/website.com.key
/home/ubuntu/ssl/gd_bundle.crt
```

As per my configuration files:

**/etc/apache2/ports.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName website.com

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

    SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /home/ubuntu/ssl/website.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/ssl/website.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ubuntu/ssl/gd_bundle.crt

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
```

The website is working fine over normal HTTP so I won't post the configuration for that (I can if you wish to see it!)

- Apache restarts without errors.
- Doesn't appear to be any errors in the error log file.

The netstat command shows apache listening on the correct port:

```
    netstat -tap | grep https
    tcp   0   0   *:https   *:*   LISTEN   24840/apache2
```

It may also be useful that I came across the **s_client** command.

```
    openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
```

When using localhost, everything appears to be normal (can't say I know what normal is, but there is a lot of relevant information output and doesn't appear to be any errors).

```
    openssl s_client -connect <ip-address>:443
    openssl s_client -connect website.com:443
```

Both of the above output errors:

```
    connect: Connection timed out
    connect:errno=110
```

I came across a lot of the diagnostic information above while trying to get SSL working, but Im not sure what to make of the information and now I am stuck.

If you need any more information just ask!

Thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 5):

The error

```
Connection timed out
```

Indicates that `openssl` can't even complete a TCP handshake on port 443 of your server.

The most likely problem is either with your `iptables` configuration or an external firewall run by your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google for [**ssl error 110**](http://www.google.com/search?q=ssl+error+110) brings up numerous issues with GoDaddy and SSL.

If GoDaddy is also your hoster, I would suggest taking it up with them, as it seems to be a problem on their side.

Comment: I followed the link and it appears to show nothing mentioning goDaddy. It does come up with information if I manually add goDaddy to the search term, but this is the same with all domain providers. Also most of the results from that link seem to indicate problems with POP rather than HTTP(s). I presumed that the 110 error was specific to the s_client command, rather than SSL.

Comment: s_client is an openssl command, and openssl is the reference implementation of the SSL protocol. so yes, this is an SSL error.

Answer (score 0):

I notice:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

In particular the `Allow from` line. So basically it is only allowing connections from localhost. So connecting to localhost:443 will work fine, but connecting by the external facing IP address won't work.

I would compare this with whatever you have in your non-SSL `<VirtualHost>` section and use that.

Comment: The block is the same in my non-SSL VirtualHost section. Also the directory I am trying to access is the root /var/www/