# Ubuntu Certbot SSL not working 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, ubuntu-18.04, certbot

I am trying to integrate SSL with my Laravel site http://enablerochester.com. I tried following the tutorial for setting up certbot on Ubuntu 18.04 here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04 however after following each step **https** still doesn't work.

Within my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` I have two files. **000-default.conf** & **default-ssl.conf**.

Here is what my **000-default.conf** looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName enablerochester.com

    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    #RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    ServerAdmin antoinesolomon5@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/production/public
    #DirectoryIndex index.php
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =testing.enablerochester.com
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

That is my basic http protocol which works perfectly. However when working with the **default-ssl.conf** I can't seem to figure out the issue:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin antoinesolomon5@gmail.com

        ServerName enablerochester.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/production/public

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.

        #   Server Certificate Chain:
        #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
        #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
        #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
        #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
        #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
        #   certificate for convinience.
        #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

        #   Certificate Authority (CA):
        #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
        #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
        #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
        #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

        #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
        #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
        #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
        #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
        #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

        #   Client Authentication (Type):
        #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
        #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
        #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
        #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
        #SSLVerifyClient require
        #SSLVerifyDepth  10

        #   SSL Engine Options:
        #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
        #   o FakeBasicAuth:
        #    Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
        #    the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
        #    user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
        #    Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
        #    file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
        #   o ExportCertData:
        #    This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
        #    SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
        #    server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
        #    authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
        #    into CGI scripts.
        #   o StdEnvVars:
        #    This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
        #    Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
        #    because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
        #    useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
        #    exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
        #   o OptRenegotiate:
        #    This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
        #    directives are used in per-directory context.
        #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
        #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
        #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
        #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
        #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
        #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
        #    This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
        #    SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
        #    the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
        #    mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
        #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
        #    This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
        #    SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
        #    alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
        #    practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
        #    works correctly.
        #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
        #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
        #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
        #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
        #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
        #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
        # BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        #       nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        #       downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/enablerochester.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/enablerochester.com/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

When running `apachectl -S` this is what I get

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   www.enablerochester.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
*:443                  enablerochester.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

As you can see the document root is the same in the ssl as it is in the standard port. Here are somethings/links I have tried to mitigate the issue:

- Completely uninstall and reinstall certbot
- Reference my past ubuntu servers with SSL running on it
- `Certbot Renew`
- Adding `.well-known`
- Running `a2ensite` & `a2dissite` in conjuction with `systemctl reload apache2`/`service apache2 restart`
- Creating new SSL certs to the point I've request too many
- Added `Listen 443` in case there was a firewall in the ports.conf
- https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/dns-a-aaaa-record-s-problem/42413
- https://medium.com/@jevgenijdmitrijev/howto-configuring-server-for-hosting-single-laravel-web-ssl-with-lets-encrypt-f670710ef827
- https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/permission-denied-to-etc-letsencrypt-live/72892
- https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/solved-urn-acme-error-unauthorized-the-client-lacks-sufficient-authorization/53238
- https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-lets-encrypt-with-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04/
- https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/this-site-can-t-be-reached/50751/6
- [Cannot get SSL working with Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/371162/cannot-get-ssl-working-with-apache)

This literally makes no sense to me as I haven't had any trouble installing and configuring ssl certs on other ubuntu servers. I've been banging my head for hours trying to solve this so any guidance in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe the exact issue you have? What did you do? What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: When I try to reach your domain I get a timeout. This usually points toward a firewall problem.

Comment: @chutz the exact issue is that the certificate has said that it has successfully installed, yet when I try to go to https for my domain it just says the site can't be reached. I am not getting any configuration errors. As in my past instances I have configured it the same exact way as right now and they've worked just fine.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I thought that may have been the issue, however within my ports.conf I added listen to 443 and when I run `ufw status` it says inactive.

Comment: Apaches ports.conf has no effect on the firewall. The firewall can be anywhere between you and your server.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider you're right man! I went into my Ec2 instance and completely forgot to add the https security group, which I guess acted as the firewall you were talking about. Forgot all about it, could've saved me hours. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem and turned out "I went into my Ec2 instance and completely forgot to add the https security group," this worked for me. thanks @SolomonAntoine